# how to deserialize array from xml

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

So, I've been trying to deserialize this XML:

```
<DCR>
   <Xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global>
      <Xcore>411</Xcore>
      <Categoria_de_Riesgo>Risk Alert</Categoria_de_Riesgo>
      <Probabilidad_de_incumplimiento>91.75</Probabilidad_de_incumplimiento>
      <HorizonteTiempo>
         <Desde>02.2018</Desde>
         <Hasta>01.2019</Hasta>
      </HorizonteTiempo>
      <Odds>
         <Odds_A_Favor>1</Odds_A_Favor>
         <Odds_EnContra>11.1</Odds_EnContra>
         <ObligorAzar>12.1</ObligorAzar>
         <ObligorIncumplimiento>11.1</ObligorIncumplimiento>
         <PorcientoDeudorIncumplimiento>97.61</PorcientoDeudorIncumplimiento>
         <PorcientoDeudorNoIncumplimiento>2.39</PorcientoDeudorNoIncumplimiento>
         <QuantilPoblacion>29.89</QuantilPoblacion>
      </Odds>
      <Mes_evaluacion>01.2018</Mes_evaluacion>
   </Xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global>
   <DeudasPorProducto>
      <Producto Nombre="Tarjeta de Crédito">
         <EstatusImg>CR</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>2</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">15000</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>23488</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota>2194</Cuota>
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado>17504</Castigado>
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Tarjeta de Crédito">
         <EstatusImg>CN</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>1</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="U.S. $">219</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado />
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="SERVICIOS">
         <EstatusImg>CR</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>1</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">2534</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>2534</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado>2534</Castigado>
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Producto de Telecomunicaciones">
         <EstatusImg>CG</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>3</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">3021</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>1979</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Préstamo">
         <EstatusImg>CN</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>2</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">40000</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado />
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Total ID="R.D. $ PESO">
         <Total_CreditoAprobado>$60,555</Total_CreditoAprobado>
         <Total_Adeudado>$28,001</Total_Adeudado>
         <Total_Cuota>$2,194</Total_Cuota>
         <Total_EnAtraso />
         <Total_EnLegal />
         <Total_Castigado>$20,038</Total_Castigado>
      </Total>
      <Total ID="U.S. $ DOLAR">
         <Total_CreditoAprobado>$219</Total_CreditoAprobado>
         <Total_Adeudado />
         <Total_Cuota />
         <Total_EnAtraso />
         <Total_EnLegal />
         <Total_Castigado />
      </Total>
   </DeudasPorProducto>
</DCR>
```

And having trouble deserializing this section:

```
<DeudasPorProducto>
      <Producto Nombre="Tarjeta de Crédito">
         <EstatusImg>CR</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>2</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">15000</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>23488</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota>2194</Cuota>
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado>17504</Castigado>
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Tarjeta de Crédito">
         <EstatusImg>CN</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>1</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="U.S. $">219</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado />
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="SERVICIOS">
         <EstatusImg>CR</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>1</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">2534</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>2534</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado>2534</Castigado>
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Producto de Telecomunicaciones">
         <EstatusImg>CG</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>3</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">3021</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado>1979</TotalAdeudado>
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Producto Nombre="Préstamo">
         <EstatusImg>CN</EstatusImg>
         <EstatusImg2 />
         <CantidadCuentas>2</CantidadCuentas>
         <CreditoAprobado Moneda="R.D. $">40000</CreditoAprobado>
         <TotalAdeudado />
         <Cuota />
         <EnAtraso />
         <EnLegal />
         <Castigado />
      </Producto>
      <Total ID="R.D. $ PESO">
         <Total_CreditoAprobado>$60,555</Total_CreditoAprobado>
         <Total_Adeudado>$28,001</Total_Adeudado>
         <Total_Cuota>$2,194</Total_Cuota>
         <Total_EnAtraso />
         <Total_EnLegal />
         <Total_Castigado>$20,038</Total_Castigado>
      </Total>
      <Total ID="U.S. $ DOLAR">
         <Total_CreditoAprobado>$219</Total_CreditoAprobado>
         <Total_Adeudado />
         <Total_Cuota />
         <Total_EnAtraso />
         <Total_EnLegal />
         <Total_Castigado />
      </Total>
   </DeudasPorProducto>
```

As you can see, the Element "Producto" is mixed up with another element called "Total", which may be why it isn't deserializing. These are the classes I'm using:

```
public  class DeudasPorProducto
    {
        [XmlElement("Producto")]
        public List<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
    }


 public class Xcore
    {
        [XmlElement("Xcore")]
        public int CrediScore { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Categoria_de_Riesgo")]
        public string CategoriaRiesgo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Probabilidad_de_incumplimiento")]
        public double ProbabilidadIncumplimiento { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("HorizonteTiempo")]
        public Timeline HorizonteTiempo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Odds")]
        public Odds Odds { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Mes_evaluacion")]
        public string MesEvaluacion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DeudasPorProducto")]
        public DeudasPorProducto Deudas { get; set; }


    }

   [XmlRoot("DCR")]
  public  class DataCreditoCreditReport
    {
        [XmlElement("Xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global")]
    public   Xcore Xcore { get; set; }
    }
```

The last thing I tried was using the Producto Class as a list as property on Xcore:

```
   [XmlArray("DeudasPorProducto")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Producto")]
    public List<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
```

But it didn't take. I need a helping hand at this point. :)

Comment: When you say "it didn't take", what do you mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It's not generating any errors.  In the first example the property "DeudasPorProducto"  is just null. For the second example the list for the property "Productos " is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the XML example in your question and paste it as a class using Visual Studio (Edit Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes) it will give you about 900 line boilerplate code (much of which is extremely redundant), but that will deserialize without problems and should give you a decent starting point.

```
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlClasses.DCR));

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"TestXml.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var dcr = (XmlClasses.DCR)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
```

You should be able to then start tweaking property names using the XmlElement attribute.

```
public class XmlClasses
{
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class DCR
    {

        private DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalField;

        private DCRDeudasPorProducto deudasPorProductoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global Xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global
        {
            get
            {
                return this.xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.xcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public DCRDeudasPorProducto DeudasPorProducto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deudasPorProductoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.deudasPorProductoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_Global
    {

        private ushort xcoreField;

        private string categoria_de_RiesgoField;

        private decimal probabilidad_de_incumplimientoField;

        private DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalHorizonteTiempo horizonteTiempoField;

        private DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalOdds oddsField;

        private decimal mes_evaluacionField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort Xcore
        {
            get
            {
                return this.xcoreField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.xcoreField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Categoria_de_Riesgo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.categoria_de_RiesgoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.categoria_de_RiesgoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal Probabilidad_de_incumplimiento
        {
            get
            {
                return this.probabilidad_de_incumplimientoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.probabilidad_de_incumplimientoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalHorizonteTiempo HorizonteTiempo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.horizonteTiempoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.horizonteTiempoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalOdds Odds
        {
            get
            {
                return this.oddsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.oddsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal Mes_evaluacion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mes_evaluacionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mes_evaluacionField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalHorizonteTiempo
    {

        private decimal desdeField;

        private decimal hastaField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal Desde
        {
            get
            {
                return this.desdeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.desdeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal Hasta
        {
            get
            {
                return this.hastaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.hastaField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRXcore_PD12M_ALL_PC_NC_GlobalOdds
    {

        private byte odds_A_FavorField;

        private decimal odds_EnContraField;

        private decimal obligorAzarField;

        private decimal obligorIncumplimientoField;

        private decimal porcientoDeudorIncumplimientoField;

        private decimal porcientoDeudorNoIncumplimientoField;

        private decimal quantilPoblacionField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte Odds_A_Favor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.odds_A_FavorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.odds_A_FavorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal Odds_EnContra
        {
            get
            {
                return this.odds_EnContraField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.odds_EnContraField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal ObligorAzar
        {
            get
            {
                return this.obligorAzarField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.obligorAzarField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal ObligorIncumplimiento
        {
            get
            {
                return this.obligorIncumplimientoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.obligorIncumplimientoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal PorcientoDeudorIncumplimiento
        {
            get
            {
                return this.porcientoDeudorIncumplimientoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.porcientoDeudorIncumplimientoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal PorcientoDeudorNoIncumplimiento
        {
            get
            {
                return this.porcientoDeudorNoIncumplimientoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.porcientoDeudorNoIncumplimientoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal QuantilPoblacion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.quantilPoblacionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.quantilPoblacionField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRDeudasPorProducto
    {

        private DCRDeudasPorProductoProducto[] productoField;

        private DCRDeudasPorProductoTotal[] totalField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Producto")]
        public DCRDeudasPorProductoProducto[] Producto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Total")]
        public DCRDeudasPorProductoTotal[] Total
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRDeudasPorProductoProducto
    {

        private string estatusImgField;

        private object estatusImg2Field;

        private byte cantidadCuentasField;

        private DCRDeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado creditoAprobadoField;

        private string totalAdeudadoField;

        private string cuotaField;

        private object enAtrasoField;

        private object enLegalField;

        private string castigadoField;

        private string nombreField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string EstatusImg
        {
            get
            {
                return this.estatusImgField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.estatusImgField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EstatusImg2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.estatusImg2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.estatusImg2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte CantidadCuentas
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cantidadCuentasField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cantidadCuentasField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public DCRDeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado CreditoAprobado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.creditoAprobadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.creditoAprobadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string TotalAdeudado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalAdeudadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalAdeudadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Cuota
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cuotaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cuotaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EnAtraso
        {
            get
            {
                return this.enAtrasoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.enAtrasoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EnLegal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.enLegalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.enLegalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Castigado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.castigadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.castigadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Nombre
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nombreField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nombreField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRDeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado
    {

        private string monedaField;

        private ushort valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Moneda
        {
            get
            {
                return this.monedaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.monedaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public ushort Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DCRDeudasPorProductoTotal
    {

        private string total_CreditoAprobadoField;

        private string total_AdeudadoField;

        private string total_CuotaField;

        private object total_EnAtrasoField;

        private object total_EnLegalField;

        private string total_CastigadoField;

        private string idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_CreditoAprobado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CreditoAprobadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CreditoAprobadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Adeudado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_AdeudadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_AdeudadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Cuota
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CuotaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CuotaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object Total_EnAtraso
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_EnAtrasoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_EnAtrasoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object Total_EnLegal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_EnLegalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_EnLegalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Castigado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CastigadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CastigadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class DeudasPorProducto
    {

        private DeudasPorProductoProducto[] productoField;

        private DeudasPorProductoTotal[] totalField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Producto")]
        public DeudasPorProductoProducto[] Producto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Total")]
        public DeudasPorProductoTotal[] Total
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DeudasPorProductoProducto
    {

        private string estatusImgField;

        private object estatusImg2Field;

        private byte cantidadCuentasField;

        private DeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado creditoAprobadoField;

        private string totalAdeudadoField;

        private string cuotaField;

        private object enAtrasoField;

        private object enLegalField;

        private string castigadoField;

        private string nombreField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string EstatusImg
        {
            get
            {
                return this.estatusImgField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.estatusImgField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EstatusImg2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.estatusImg2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.estatusImg2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte CantidadCuentas
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cantidadCuentasField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cantidadCuentasField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public DeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado CreditoAprobado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.creditoAprobadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.creditoAprobadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string TotalAdeudado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalAdeudadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalAdeudadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Cuota
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cuotaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cuotaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EnAtraso
        {
            get
            {
                return this.enAtrasoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.enAtrasoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object EnLegal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.enLegalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.enLegalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Castigado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.castigadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.castigadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Nombre
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nombreField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nombreField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DeudasPorProductoProductoCreditoAprobado
    {

        private string monedaField;

        private ushort valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Moneda
        {
            get
            {
                return this.monedaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.monedaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public ushort Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DeudasPorProductoTotal
    {

        private string total_CreditoAprobadoField;

        private string total_AdeudadoField;

        private string total_CuotaField;

        private object total_EnAtrasoField;

        private object total_EnLegalField;

        private string total_CastigadoField;

        private string idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_CreditoAprobado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CreditoAprobadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CreditoAprobadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Adeudado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_AdeudadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_AdeudadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Cuota
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CuotaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CuotaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object Total_EnAtraso
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_EnAtrasoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_EnAtrasoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object Total_EnLegal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_EnLegalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_EnLegalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Total_Castigado
        {
            get
            {
                return this.total_CastigadoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.total_CastigadoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver. Turns out I was trying to put the property for the Class I couldn't serialize inside the wrong class.

It should've been inside DataCreditoCreditReport instead of inside of Xcore. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) web service to generate classes with necessary attributes.

The service returns C# classes which you can rename with your coding style.

I have checked generated classes and it works fine.

My fiddler is here: [.NET Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vFmUvN)

You need to use next declaration for Producte class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="DeudasPorProducto")]
public class DeudasPorProducto {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Producto")]
    public List<Producto> Producto { get; set; }
}
```